# Convert Varchar to Interval

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, cast, interval

I have a Postgresql column that is a varchar that is saving a string that looks like `'2 years, 5 months'` or `'3 months'` or `'9 years, 0 months`'.  I can't convert the column to an interval because it's going to break a bunch of existing functionality so what I am trying to do is cast that varchar into an interval in the select statement.  I can't figure out how to do this, I was thinking I first need to format it into a timestamp then turn that into an interval?  But haven't been able to find any info about this specific case.Thanks for the help!

Edit 1:  a_horse_with_no_name's solution worked but I was getting an error previously because of the empty rows so I wrote a case like so to fix it

```
case
  when
    duration = ''
  then
    interval '0'
  else
    duration::interval
end
```

Comment: Is it always 'years & month' and 'month', or there are other formats?

Comment: @McNets It is either `'years, months'`, `'months'`, `'empty'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values all follow the syntax you have shown, you can simply cast it to an interval:

```
select '2 years, 5 months'::interval
```